# Distance of line from origin - 3D question

Tags: analytic-geometry, 3d

I am stuck in this question for a while. Please help me out. 
Question is simple but I am not able to find the exact answer.

prove that the planes $$ ny-mz = λ , lz- nx =μ  $$and $$ mx - ly =ν $$ 
have a common line if$$ lλ + mμ + n ν =0 $$
. show that the distance of the line from the origin is
$$ \sqrt {\frac{ λ^2 + μ^2 + ν^2}   {l^2 + m^2 + n^2}} $$

I got the first part but it's second part that's is troubling me. 
Please , can anyone help me with this question. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn’t the second plane equation be $lz-nx=\mu$?

Comment: Yes, sorry for that

Comment: Can anyone please try this out